# Django receiving json post request from external source

Tags: python, json, django, labview

I have written a view function that processes a post request containing json data from a source outside of django (labview). I'm just testing it to begin with so it looks like this

```
def post_entry(request):
    '''Process incoming json string
    '''

    if request.method == 'POST':

        post_data = request.body

    # Return a response
    return HttpResponse('data received OK')
```

I've written a test to test this and it passes fine:

```
def test_post_entry_view_good_post_data(self):
    '''post_entry view should return a 200 status if valid
    '''

    data = {'DHTP Data': ['10', '50.296', '50.94', '50.418', '50.425', '50.431', '50.94'],
        'Test String': 'My Test String'}

    request_url = reverse('post_entry') 
    response = self.client.post(request_url, content_type='application/json', 
        data=dumps(data))

    # Should return a 200 response indicating ok
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But when labview posts the data `post_entry` returns a 403 forbidden error. I guess this is due to no csrf token being present, but why does the test pass in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test client works around the CSRF functionality.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#testing

Comment: Thanks makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to have a view that accepts post data from a source external to your app you need to make your view exempt from CSRF protection by using [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt):

```
@csrf_exempt
def post_entry(request):
    '''Process incoming json string
    '''
```

If you are going to do this, you should use some other method of validating the request

Answer (score 2):

If your view is supposed to accept `POST` from external sources it is upon you to validate the request as every `POST` request is required to have a CSRF token (Refer: [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)). Hence, for your purpose, you'll have to exempt the view from CSRF validation using `@csrf_exempt` decorator and write your own validation for the request using something like [Token Authentication](https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi)

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to get the decorator needed to bypass CSRF protection:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

then put the @csrf_exempt decorator on the line before your function.